# Spark notebook in Hue 3.11

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, hue

I am trying to setup Spark notebook in HUE(version 3.11) with Spark 2.0.0 using Livy  0.2.0. 
With Spark 1.6.1 the notebook is working perfectly fine.

Livy only supports Scala 2.10 builds of Spark.So I did a build of Spark-2.0.0 with Scala-2.10.6.When I open up spark-shell(2.0.0) it clears says "Using Scala version 2.10.6".
But Spark notebook is not working with this build.In the Spark notebook when I do 1+1 and execute it , it gives the following error.
What could be wrong here?Below is the exception in the logs

```
           "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.cloudera.livy.rsc.rpc.RpcException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.render(Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;)Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;\ncom.cloudera.livy.repl.ReplDriver$$anonfun$handle$2.apply(ReplDriver.scala:78)\ncom.cloudera.livy.repl.ReplDriver$$anonfun$handle$2.apply(ReplDriver.scala:78)\nscala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)\ncom.cloudera.livy.repl.ReplDriver.handle(ReplDriver.scala:78)\nsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\nsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)\nsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\njava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)\ncom.cloudera.livy.rsc.rpc.RpcDispatcher.handleCall(RpcDispatcher.java:130)\ncom.cloudera.livy.rsc.rpc.RpcDispatcher.channelRead0(RpcDispatcher.java:77)\nio.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)\nio.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)\nio.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)\nio.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)\nio.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)\nio.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)\nio.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)\nio.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec.channelRead(ByteToMessageCodec.java:103)\nio.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)\nio.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)\nio.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)\nio.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)\nio.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)\nio.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)\nio.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)\nio.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)\nio.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)\njava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" (error 500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem.
Download latest Livy code from Git hub.Use the below maven build command

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dspark-2.0 -Dscala-2.11
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is even possible.
Relying on [release notes](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/docs/release-notes/release-notes-3.11.0.txt#L77), Hue 3.11 not works with Spark 2.0 (it works with Spark 1.6).

Comment: Livy provides a rest interface to access Spark,hue is just a client for Livy.I think problem is something else

Comment: Yes, would recommend to check if livy.io supports Spark 2.0